Show Div when other div is visible (no Jquery)
Right now I am using Jquery to show a div when a other Div from a result (after search) is visible. The results create a div with all ID's
div id1, id2, id3 and so on.
I use this code:
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>        
<script>
    $("#Div5").is(":visible")&&$("#Div3").after('<div class="between">tekst</div>'),
    $("#Div6").is(":visible")&&$("#Div5").after('<div class="between">tekst</div>');
</script>

I am not using Jquery anywhere else on the website.
Is there a better way to get the same results, but without having to load the full jquery.

This question is similar to: Check if element is visible in DOM. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

To achieve this functionality, you can use plain JavaScript to check if a div is visible and then dynamically insert another div based on that condition.
<script>
    function addDivs() {
        function isVisible(element) {
            return element.offsetParent !== null;
        }

        // check visibility of divs and insert new ones
        const div5 = document.getElementById("Div5");
        const div6 = document.getElementById("Div6");
        const div3 = document.getElementById("Div3");

        if (div5 && isVisible(div5)) {
            const newDiv = document.createElement("div");
            newDiv.className = "between";
            newDiv.textContent = "tekst"; 
            div3.insertAdjacentElement("afterend", newDiv);
        }

        if (div6 && isVisible(div6)) {
            const newDiv = document.createElement("div");
            newDiv.className = "between";
            newDiv.textContent = "tekst";
            div5.insertAdjacentElement("afterend", newDiv);
        }
    }

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
       addDivs();
    });
</script>

The key point is when the visibility check runs: just when DOMContent is loaded: isVisible checks if the element is visible on the page. It does this by checking the offsetParent property, which returns null if the element is hidden (either via display: none or visibility: hidden).
If you need to run it also on DOM change, you can add also MutationObserver which is the basic (and most performance-efficient) way to run code on change.
    const observer = new MutationObserver(() => {
        addDivs();
    });

    // observing every insertion in body
    // (use different HTMLElement to be more precise)
    observer.observe(document.body, {
        childList: true, // monitoring children insertions
        subtree: true     // also in depth
    });

Hope this helps! Let me know if you need further clarification!

Thanks, I got it to run just fine. I missed the offsetParent property (still learning). But what if i Needed to add 2 div's (with different classes), how do i go on with that? ("between1", "between2"). But it's content (textContent) is different for both what i can't seem to get right and display's the same.

To add two divs with different classes and content, create a new div element for the first one. Set its class to "between1" and assign the desired content. Then, insert this new div after the target div (in your case, div3).
Next, repeat the process for the second div. Create another div, set its class to "between2", and assign its own content.
By following this pattern iteratively, you can dynamically create and position divs with distinct classes and content in DOM.
If this helps you, please consider accepting the answer!  Let me know if you need any further clarification!
